# Can the constructor of a class return another class in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I'm currently playing around with 2D geometry. I created two classes: `Point` and `LineSegment`:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class LineSegment:
    def __init__(self, p1: Point, p2: Point):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
```

An interesting case is `LineSegment(p1, p1)` - hence a line segment of length zero. Essentially, this is just the point `p1`. But it is of type `LineSegment`.

I will likely use something like the following to deal with that case:

```
class LineSegment:
    def __init__(self, p1: Point, p2: Point):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    def simplify(self):
        if self.p1 == self.p2:
            return self.p1
        return self
```

Although it is likely a very bad idea, I'm still curious: **Is it possible to make the constructor of class `LineSegment` return an object of class `Point`?**

Comment: constructor to return an instance of another class? No, but you can override the \_\_new\_\_ method.

Comment: You could create a function ‘makeLineSegment()’ which detects the special case and returns the right instance.

Comment: `__new__` needs to return object from the same class, `__init__` return value is ignored. Other normal methods can return whatever they want. Like a method ``to_Point(self)`` returning a Point object.

Comment: Well `__new__` does not really has to, but notice from Python docs: If `__new__()` does not return an instance of cls, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, though not the constructor `__init__()`, but the instantiator [`__new__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

```
class LineSegment:
    def __new__(cls, p1: Point, p2: Point):
        # Using "is" here since Points are mutable, but that's just personal preference
        if p1 is p2:
            return p1
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, p1: Point, p2: Point):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

a = Point(0, 0)
b = Point(1, 1)
print(LineSegment(a, b))  # <__main__.LineSegment object at ...>
print(LineSegment(a, a))  # <__main__.Point object at ...>
```

Note, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

> If `__new__()` does not return an instance of *cls*, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

Comment: P.s. I'm not super deep into OOP so I can't speak to whether it's a good idea or not, but it definitely feels wrong.

Comment: This is fine; depending on how instances of `LineSegement` are *used*, there might be an argument for maintaining the distinction between a degenerate line segment and its single point.

Comment: `p1 is p2` is not ideal, because then the simplification wont work for `LineSegment(Point(0,0), Point(0,0))`

Comment: @Wombatz Actually that's on purpose, like chepner said above it's to distinguish between a line with 0 length and a point, especially since these point objects are mutable.

Comment: Well, a degenerate line segment is a point, whether or not the same Python object represents the point in each argument. I guess my stance is: there's no problem returning a object of a different type from `__new__`, as long as it makes sense to do so. The exact circumstances under which it makes sense is an entirely different question.

Comment: @chepner Ah ok, I might have misunderstood you, or missed the subtelty

Comment: I think I would go with `==` in this case, as there shouldn't be any reason to distinguish between two `Point` objects representing the same point.