# How do I resolve AttributeError: "Pages" object has no attribute "pages"

Tags: python, class

I have a few custom classes that look like this:

```py
from typing import List
from typing_extensions import Self

class Page:
    def __init__(self, search_id: str, page_num: int) -> None:
        self.search_id = search_id
        self.page_num = page_num
        self.isLast = False

    def mark_as_last(self):
        self.isLast = True
```

```py
class Pages:
    def __new__(cls: Self, search_id: str, range_of_pages: List[int]):
        instance = super(Pages, cls).__new__(cls)
        return instance.pages

    def __init__(self, search_id: str, range_of_pages: List[int]):
        self.search_id = search_id
        self.ranges_of_pages = range_of_pages
        self.pages = Pages.create_pages(self.ranges_of_pages, self.search_id)

    @staticmethod
    def create_pages(range_of_pages: List[int], search_id: str) -> List[Page]:
        pages = []
        for page_num in range_of_pages:
            page = Page(search_id, page_num)
            if page_num == range_of_pages[-1]:
                page.mark_as_last()
            pages.append(page)
        return pages

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.pages[item]
```

When 'Pages' is called like `Pages('123', [1, 2, 3, 4])`, I want to return a list of pages - see `return instance.pages`

Well... when I get to this point, I get an error. Specifically this error:

```
def __new__(cls: Self, search_id: str, range_of_pages: List[int]):
        instance = super(Pages, cls).__new__(cls)
        return instance.pages
E       AttributeError: 'Pages' object has no attribute 'pages'
```

Am I missing something? This should work. I have no idea what is wrong here.

Comment: Why did you expect that a `Pages` object has a `pages` attribute at this point?

Comment: Why do you implement `__new__` at all? What do you intend to do here?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I wanted to instantiate the Pages class from the __new__ method and return the instance.pages attribute. I honestly just did it this way for the type hints.

I have function that has a signature like this:
```
T = TypeVar('T')
def dosomething(arr: List[T]) -> List[T]
```
If my Pages class returns a List[Page] then I'll better hints, no?

Comment: But returning `instance.pages` doesn't make sense to begin with, `Pages.__new__` should return a `Pages` instance, not a `List[Page]`. What happens if you just delete the whole `__new__` method?

Comment: @mkrieger1 if I delete it, my call won't look how I want it to. I would need to instantiate the Pages class and get the pages attribute :/

```
Pages(...).pages
```

Comment: But at least your code won't crash with an AttributeError. And why do you need to get the `pages` attribute if the `Pages` class has methods to access it from outside?

Comment: @mkrieger1 because that's just how I want it to work. I just want to call `Pages(..)`
and get back List[Page]. I don't want an instance of Pages.

Comment: Well if you don't want a `Pages` instance, then you don't need a `Pages` class. You just need a function which returns s list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea to return an object from `__new__` that is of a different type than the class, but it is possible (see e.g. [Can the constructor of a class return another class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61548276/can-the-constructor-of-a-class-return-another-class-in-python)).

In your case you were trying to access and return the `.pages` attribute of the newly created `Pages` object before it was initialized in `__init__`, which is called *after* `__new__`.

Since `__new__` depends on everything that currently happens in `__init__`, you have to move everything into `__new__`.

```
class Pages:
    def __new__(cls: Self, search_id: str, range_of_pages: List[int]):
        instance = super(Pages, cls).__new__(cls)
        instance.search_id = search_id
        instance.ranges_of_pages = range_of_pages
        return Pages.create_pages(ranges_of_pages, search_id)
```

But that really makes me wonder why this class is needed at all. The `search_id` and `ranges_of_pages` attributes do not seem to be needed anywhere else (in fact they *can't* be, because the `Pages` instance is immediately discarded), so you could just remove the class and make `create_pages` a free function.

Answer (score 1):

`__new__` handles the creation of a class instance, whereas `__init__` initializes it. Since `__new__` runs before `__init__`, the created instance does not yet have the `pages` attribute which is assigned in `__init__`.